# FF92.0 on linux introduces caching issues with django 3.2 inline forms

Tags: django, firefox, django-forms, browser-cache

I've noticed a strange behavior with FF 92.0 (Manjaro Linux, but likely all linux I guess) when using inline forms.

Setup:

- Django inline forms
- A way to add inlines ajax. I'm using the django forms empty_form
- Some arbitray # of inline saved on the server for that object (for example, say 3)
- Load the form, add say 2 inlines using javascript. TOTAL_FORMS now shows value=5
- Do NOT submit the form, but F5 for a refresh instead
- After reload, the inlines shown in the table will mirror that of the server
- However the TOTAL_FORMS from the management_form will show value=5, instead of the 3 it should.

page.js:

```
function insert_inlinedets_form () {
    let form_idx = $('#id_details-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    console.log("inserting new form " + form_idx);
    let newrow = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo($('#details_form'));
    newrow.append($('#empty_form_inlinedets').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
    $('#id_details-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx)+1);
    console.log("added row to inlinedets formset");
};

function remove_inlinedets_form () {
    console.log("remove last form ");
    let form_idx = $('#id_details-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    if (form_idx>0) {
        $('#details_form > tr').last().remove();
        $('#id_details-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx)-1);    
        console.log("removed row from inlinedets");
        calc_grand_total();                                 // existing rows haven't changed but the total might
    } else {
        $('#id_details-TOTAL_FORMS').val();                 // if no form left, this SHOULD be 0.    
        console.log("No more dets left - nothing done.");
    }
};
```

html - empty form:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="empty_form_inlinedets">
                {% for field in formset.empty_form %}
                {% if field.is_hidden %}
                <td style="display:none;">{{field}}</td>
                {% else %}
                <td>{{field}}</td>
                {% endif %}         
                {% endfor %}        
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

html - target table to append to:

```
<div class="table-responsive shadow encart">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
    <table class="table table-bordered dbase-table" id="bottom_product_form" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <caption style="caption-side:top">Products</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- th content -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="details_form">
            {% for form in formset %}
            <tr>
                <!-- td content -->
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have validated the following:

- The response.rendered_content that the server returns does indeed show the correct TOTAL_FORMS number (3, in the above example)
- This does NOT happen upon a hard refresh (ctrl shift r on FF). TOTAL_FORMS, under the same setup, shows the correct # of 3.
- This does NOT happen on Google Chrome upon a normal refresh.

So.... any ideas on how I should approach this? What setting could be causing the issue? Please consider in any answer:

- I won't have control of user behavior. So simply "not using soft refresh on FF" isn't valid.
- I won't have control of user browser settings, so adjusting some settings wouldn't really work (although KNOWING which FF setting may cause the issue is still useful)